# Docker returning response only for http port

Tags: c#, docker, https

Here is the part of the docker compose

```
ecommerce.supplier:
    container_name: supplier
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}ecommercesupplier
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ECommerce.Supplier/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "5000:80"
        - "5001:443"
    env_file: ECommerce.Common/Common.env
    environment:
        - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=host.docker.internal\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=ECommerceSupplier;User Id=sa;Password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
        - ./.aspnet/supplier/DataProtection-Keys:/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys
    networks: 
        - ecommerce-network
```

Here is part of the Docker file for this service which exposes the ports. The file is auto generated by visual studio.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Here is docker ps:

[image]

So what is the result of all of this. When I hit http://localhost:5000/api/V1/Supplier/getlist with get request with proper token I receive a response. But if I try with same end point with https://localhost:5001 I receive "Could not get any response" in postman.

How I can make it work on https://localhost:5001. My level in dev ops is beginner, so if you want additional information please consider to explain carefully what exactly you need.

Side note this is happening for the all services in the screenshot.

Comment: What port docker file exposes is irrelevant. Your docker-compose file directs localhost:5000 to container port 80, and localhost:5001 to container port 443. If localhost:5001 is not working, then the most likely reason is that the application running in that container is not listening to port 443.

Comment: you should go inside docker and curl it on 443 (from inside the docker). Probably when starting the web application only binding on port 80 is used. Event if your docker is bound 5001->443, the web application do not accept requests on 443.

Comment: @ddfra can you tell me how I can curl it on 443, because my knowledge in linux is below 0. I link is also ok, I try to research it, but I did not succeed for 10 min. I go into the bash with docker exec -it af bash

Comment: if you have an homepage then "curl https://localhost:443" should be enough. Is it a web site or a API server? (Stack overflow is removing https : / / in the curl command)

Comment: @ddfra it is API server. curl localhost:80 is working, curl localhost:443 is returning failed to connect to localhost port 443. So your suggestion was correct. By curl localhost:80 is working I mean it does not retun an error

Comment: do you have a resource that can be easily be retrieved by GET? something like /api/users? then do "curl https://localhost:443/api/users" (always add https:// before localhost)

Comment: first of all - what does "curl" (and nothing else) print in the shell?

Comment: @ddfra It tells me try 'curl-help' or 'curl --manual' for more information. If the 443 port is not active in my docker, how I could run the application on the 443 ? How I can do that in the docker file.

Comment: @BurakSerdar so I can make it listen to 443 ?

Comment: I found out this two guides: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1  .

Comment: @ddfra It looks like this is the problem, post both links as answer I will research it and check it. If this is the answer I accept it. I will upvote it for the help, thanks for your time

Comment: thank you @mybirthname

Comment: One more thing @mybirthname, probably the best thing to do is to leave docker listening only for http requests and let handle the SSL part to you web server (IIS / Nginx / Apache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that, inside your docker container, the application is not listening on 443.

Maybe these two links may help you:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I would give a look at this part:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapp:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
    ports:
      - 80
      - 443
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

at the environment.ASPNETCORE_URLS property.

Hope this is helpful.